# This VB code suddenly broke. Is it correct?

Tags: mysql, ms-access

My linked tables in Microsoft Access suddenly started returning every field with a value of #DELETED.  I decided to import the tables instead, and just schedule a task to do it periodically instead of dealing with the key violations that the queries cause when run against the old linked tables (oddly, relinking the tables fixes some of them temporarily.  Importing seems to fix it for good.)

However, the code is still broken.  Oddly, this VB code now returns an error.  It's short, but as follows:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

If IsLoaded("consumer_info") Then
 Me.Text0.Value = Forms!Consumer_Info.contract_name
Else
 Me.Text0.Value = Forms!frmAllentownMasterGeneration.cboContract
End If
End Sub
```

In an SQL query, here's the same information being referenced:

```
WHERE (((billing_days_allentown.Month)=[Forms]![frmBillingAllentownSelection]![cboMonth]) AND ((billing_days_allentown.Year)=[Forms]![frmBillingAllentownSelection]![cboYear]) AND ((billing_days_allentown.contract_name)=[Forms]![frmBillingAllentownSelection]![cboContract]) AND ((location_info.primary_address)="-1"));
```

Does anything obvious seem to have broken my code?  I'd appreciate any help at all!

Comment: What is the error message and which code statement triggers it?

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you move that code from `Form_Open` to `Form_Load`?

Answer (score 0):

You may need a bang (!) instead of a pop (.) when referencing the field names.  Such as:

```
 Me.Text0.Value = Forms!Consumer_Info!contract_name
```

instead of

```
Me.Text0.Value = Forms!Consumer_Info.contract_name
```

Or you may even need to spell it all out like:

```
Me.Text0.Value = Forms!Consumer_Info!contract_name.Value
```

A good rule of thumb is; **If you created it, bang it**.  That explains why your form and field names (named with words you created, like "Consumer_Info") need to be preceded by a bang, and words like "text" and "value" (which are inherent to the language) are preceded by a pop.